# How can I know if a network is password-protected before connecting to it?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

What command can I run to determine the security of a wireless network, without needing to connect to it? I want to know if it needs a password to connect or if it's a public network without security. I'm mostly concerned with Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to this forum, I know you don't mean every network in the World, of course not, so try to [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/120351/edit) your question and be more specific, distribution?, GUI or command line ? what do you mean by secure , what do you want ? What do you want to find out ?

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: i want to execute a command to know  if the wireless network need a password to connect to it or not !

Comment: That can be known immediately from whatever you try to connect, be it network manager, `iwlist`. Why you want to know?

Comment: i want to build something similar to the network manager !
you cannot understand things until you try them, that's my point of view

Comment: a kind of an automatic things ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing of course would be to try and connect, if it asks you for a password, then you know it needs one.

Another approach, presumably closer to what you had in mind is

```
/sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan
```

The command above will use the wireless interface `wlan0` (change it to the name of the interface on your machine) to scan the available wireless networks. It returns a lot of information, so to simplify, parse its output:

```
/sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan | 
    awk -F: '{if($1~/Encryption/){k=$2}if($1~/ESSID/){print $2,k}}'
```

That will print a list of ESSIDs (network names) like this:

```
Network1 on
Network2 off
```

Where `on` means that the network is using encryption and `off` that it isn't.

Comment: can an open network(doesn't need password) use encryption in their communications

Comment: It [can, theoretically](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35867/why-isnt-open-wifi-encrypted) but no, in practice today, an open network won't be encrypted.